# Remove Spinner if registration throws error

Tags: reactjs

I have a registration component, that will display a spinner when user enters registration information until it opens next page.
But if the registration throws out an error like "A user with that username already exists." the loader is still showing.
I would like that in case of an error it disapeears.

I have an `onSubmit` method

```
 onSubmit = (e) => {
    this.setState({ saving: true });
    // MixPanel Tracking
    Mixpanel.track('[Register] - Submit');
    const { name, city, countries, whyTravel, whoTravel, loveTravel, hateTravel } = this.state

    const answers = {
      'why': whyTravel,
      'who': whoTravel,
      'love': loveTravel,
      'hate': hateTravel
    }
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        this.props.register(values.email, values.password, name, city, countries, answers);
        Mixpanel.track('[Register] - Successful Submission');
      }
    });
  }
```

and in my render method I have

```
{this.state.saving && 
 <LoadingSpinner /> }
```

I am not sure what I should do ?

here is a screenshot of the error I get on registring with an existing email adress.
[image: error message]

Not sure where this is coming from exactly

Comment: You probably just need an else-block where you set this.setState({ saving: false })

Comment: yep tried that one but when user registers succesfully the spinner doesn't show anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are not resetting `saving` to false after you are done.

```
  this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
    if (!err) {
      this.props.register(values.email, values.password, name, city, countries, answers);
      Mixpanel.track('[Register] - Successful Submission');
    }
    this.setState({ saving: false });
  });
```

**Update:**

```
onSubmit = (e) => {
  this.setState({ saving: true }, () => {
    // MixPanel Tracking
    Mixpanel.track('[Register] - Submit');
    const { name, city, countries, whyTravel, whoTravel, loveTravel, hateTravel } = this.state;
    const { form: { validateFields }, register } = this.props;
    const answers = {
      'why': whyTravel,
      'who': whoTravel,
      'love': loveTravel,
      'hate': hateTravel
    };
    validateFields((err, { email, password }) => {
      if (!err) {
        register(email, password, name, city, countries, answers).then(() => {
          Mixpanel.track('[Register] - Successful Submission');
          // redirect?? change the page you are showing?? 
        }).catch(() => {
          // Something went wrong. Hide the spinner.
          this.setState({ saving: false });
        });
      } else {
        // Hide the spinner, it's not loading anymore. Show the error you got from the form validation
        this.setState({ saving: false });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: In fact I already tried that. It is working but, even if user registers succesfully the spinner is not showing anymore

Comment: Isn't that the expected behavior?
If not, you can move the `this.setState({ saving: false });` inside an `else` block

Comment: The expected behavior would be to have the spinner showing while its loading until displaying new page. Resetting the state to `false` doesn't make the job as the spinner never shows up

Comment: ```this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        this.setState({ saving: true });
        this.props.register(values.email, values.password, name, city, countries, answers);
        Mixpanel.track('[Register] - Successful Submission');
      } else { this.setState({ saving: false });}
    });``` doesn't do the job

Comment: But how do you know if `this.props.register` executed without errors? You should be handling those errors as well. (`try/catch`, return a boolean value back, if it's async you can use `.then(// do your mixpanel thing here).catch(// hide the spinner here)`)
Also, will that `register` function redirect or show a different page somehow if everything is ok?

Comment: @Fabian I just updated my answer. I moved everything inside the setState callback (remember it's async so it doesn't ensure that on the following lines you will have the updated value) and also added some handling for the `register` function assuming it's async. Change it accordingly if that's not the case.

Comment: Thanks so much for the time you put into solving that issue ! It works perfectly :) Thanks for giving me a global vision not just a solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the states your `Form`s `Container` component can have. From your show case, it can be: `saving`, `success`, `error`, `default`, where default is the state where user is entering the data.

The answers above show how you can use conditional rendering to do that, in my answer I will show you common pitfalls to avoid and a way to handle errors.

## Handling UI state as boolean flags

The simplest way to support UI states would be to stuff each state as a boolean flag in your state. Something like:

```
state: {
    isSaving: false, 
    isError: false, 
    isSuccess: false,
    ... 
}
```

That has a problem that your UI state can be in an impossible state, i.e. `isSaving` & `isError`. This is what you are currently facing. The simple way to avoid it would be to use an `enum` like data structure to capture the UI state. Something like:

```
state: {
   appState: 'saving', // or error, or validationError, or success, or etc.
   ...
}
```

Then you need to `setState` appropriately in the right places, for e.x. when you trigger submission, setState to appState 'saving', if you have validationErrors, setState to 'validation' error. In your promise chain, set it to success or error. This would avoid accidental problems that you are facing and give you a granular control.

### Error Handling

React 16. introduced the concept of [ErrorBoundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) with the `componentDidCatch` lifecycle method. Do use them for having a graceful failure in your components.